# Meteor: Composite publish to get data from two collections

Tags: javascript, meteor

I try to use `reywood:publish-composite`. But something I'm doing wrong as I want to load the article-data and the assigned literature-data.
I think my main problem is to set the route correctly to get the data into the variables, which I could use in the template.

Persume I would open `/article/BpsCfbhZuoXfEvREG`:

**publications.js**

```
Meteor.publishComposite('articles', function(){
    return {
        find: function(){
            return Articles.find();
        },
        children: [{
            find: function(article){
                return Literature.find({'article.detail.reference': article._id})
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

**router.js**

```
Router.route('/article/:_id', {
    name: 'article',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('articles'); /* correct? */
    },
    data: function () {
        return { 
            article: Articles.findOne({
                _id: this.params._id
            }),
            references: Literature.find({}) /* guess, this is wrong */
        };
    }
});
```

Literature has this structure and I'm looking for `reference`:

```
{
    "_id" : "YAEYvJ7tvXxTvnFtv",
    "article" : [
        {
            "title" : "Article 1",
            "detail" : [
                {
                    "reference" : "BpsCfbhZuoXfEvREG",
                    "year" : 2000,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to load an individual article? That looks like what you are doing but you are subscribing to *all* articles. You could pass the parameter to your subscription.

```
waitOn: function () {
  return Meteor.subscribe('article', this.params._id);
}
```

Secondly, since your Literature is an array of objects, you should use `$elemMatch`

```
Meteor.publishComposite('article', function (articleId) {
  check(articleId, String);
  return {
    find: function () {
      return Articles.find(articleId);
    },
    children: [{
      find: function (article) {
        return Literature.find({ 
          'article.detail': {
            $elemMatch: {
              'reference': article._id 
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. And what do I have to do, to get the data into variables for using in the template? Yes, I want to get one single article and multiple assigned literature.

Comment: What you have looks fine. Is it not reacting as expected? If so, what seems wrong about it?